# How to correctly set up docker volumes so data persists

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, timescaledb

I am running a django application with a timescaledb image. Somehow every time I spin up a new docker container the database is created anew and the data I have created does not persist. I think it might be a problem with the configuration of the volumes, because this should be the place where the data is stored. My docker-compose file called `local.yml`:

```
version: "3.5"

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django:
    container_name: my_name
    image: my_image
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    container_name: postgres_postgis
    image: timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg14.7-ts2.10.2-latest
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
```

My problem is that I do not quite understand the volumes setup. I know that `local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data` is mapping the data folder into the image. But the `local_postgres_data` is also an empty dict. So this might be a problem, but I am not sure. I am not sure what other directory I should map into the timescale image though. I am reading that having a volume correctly set up should make the data persist even if the image is deleted and pulled anew. This is not the case in my setup. Everything gets deleted, even my supersuser.

I am using `docker-compose -f local.yml up` to start the project.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: please share the commands you use to raise your setup

Comment: @rok Thanks and sure. I updated the question. I am basically using `docker-compose -f local.yml up`  to start the setup

Comment: please double check your docker compose yml and edit acordingly, raising just postgres service fails... with the code you provided.

Comment: @rok Sorry. I checked again and added the missing `env_file` directive. I cannot share my envs, but it's just POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_PASSWORD and POSTGRES_DB in there

Comment: Hello @shadow, do you read the Docker documentation?, try to look it in order to fully understand how a [Docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume/) works, after that, you should look so the [Postgres config.](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md) for Docker

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure if it is even a problem with the volumes anymore. Everytime I delete a container and up it again django applies all migrations anew and the DB gets initialized again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
volumes:
  local_postgres_data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: 'none'
      o: 'bind'
      device: /path/to/db/files/on/host
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind to explain? I am not sure what my database fieles on host should be

Comment: If you need to have database data persist, need to locate it in a stable place on the disk. Described above approach let you achieve this.